# IntelliJ IDEA: Unknown html tag mat-card

Tags: html, angular, intellij-idea

[image: RJswz.png]

[image: EB82K.png]

As shown in the pictures above, I am having a tag inspection issue within IntelliJ IDEA. The situation is the Angular component codes being inside HTML file.

Comment: You need to import `MatCardModule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of tinkering with the plugins, it seems that the Angular and AngularJS plugins were actually disabled in IntelliJ IDEA Community version. Hence, I switched to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version and BAM! the issue is solved.
I installed it with default setting and 30-days free trials.

There was no other way if you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you are forced to use Ultimate version for the feature.